# Unable to get OnItemClickListener to function for Android in Java

Tags: java, android, listview, onitemclicklistener

I am fairly new to Java and have had little experience with listviews. I have been able to successfully add items to a listview with a custom list adapter. However, I now want to perform actions when each item is touched.

I have not been able to get the OnItemClickListener event to execute when a list item is touched, i am not sure where the problem lies.

**Code:**

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment implements OnItemClickListener{
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) { 

    View V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);

    ListView listView = (ListView)V.findViewById(R.id.list);


        getData data = getData.getMyData();


      CustomList adapter = new
            CustomList(getActivity(), data.Headline.toArray(new String[data.Headline.size()]), data.Description.toArray(new String[data.Description.size()]), data.imageId.toArray(new Integer[data.imageId.size()]));      
      listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return V;

}

public void onItemClickListener(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
{
    Log.e("CLICKED","CLICKED");
}
}
```

**Also if it helps, here is the code to the custom adapter class:**

```
public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

private final Activity context;
private final String[] titleId;
private final String[] descriptionId;
private final Integer[] pictureid;

public CustomList(Activity context,
String[] Headline, String[] Description, Integer[] imageId) {
super(context, R.layout.single_row, Headline);
this.context = context;
this.titleId = Headline;
this.descriptionId = Description;
this.pictureid = imageId;

}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row, null, true);

TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
TextView txtDescription = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ivIcon);

txtTitle.setText(titleId[position]);
txtDescription.setText(descriptionId[position]);
imageView.setImageResource(pictureid[position]);
return rowView;
}

}
```

Comment: listView.setOnItemClickListener(this); just after setAdapter()

Comment: Thank you, after I added this I was prompted to add unimplemented methods which was OnItemClick instead of OnItemClickListener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use listView.setOnItemClickListener to link the callbacks to the view.

You can do as follows:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view,int pos, long id) {
        //Your code here
    }
});
```

But, in your case, as the activity already implements OnItemClickListener() you can simply:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the listener to your ListView:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Log.e("CLICKED","CLICKED");
    }
});
```